# Why won't the drum turn in my GE washing machine?

Tags: washing-machine

Our GE washing machine has a drum that won't turn at all, but the pulley turns.  It also makes a 'ch,ch,ch,ch' sound.  The belt was replaced because it had been 'chewed up' ~ thinking the other problem caused the belt to go bad.  What might be causing this problem?

Comment: Does the drum turn freely by hand?

Comment: Check for free rotation of the drum. If it won't rotate, then you may have had the drum brakes fail. If it spins freely, then you might have had the drum clutch fail.

Comment: It doesn't spin freely, so might be the drum brakes as you suggest.